# SPServices/jQuery and rich text fields

Tags: spservices

I'm trying to use SPServices to render rich text on a page using the GetListItems method. I've seen a couple of articles with different solutions (jQuery to get rich text) but I'm still not very clear on the implementation. Any help would be appreciated :)

I'm using SharePoint 2013 and I have an image library with a multi-line text column. I've enabled rich text on this column using SPD. I'm using a CEWP, which is linked to the below html file, to render the image and description from the library on to the page.

[image: SPServices html file]

The result from the above snippet is that the text from the Description field is displayed on the page but as plain text only. The rich text formatting is presented as html tags.

How can render the rich text formatting?

Answer (score 1):

This isn’t a SharePoint thing or an SPServices thing, but a jQuery thing. If you have a string containing HTML, you can set the contents of any selected container with .html(). See: http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: So you mean $('#cards').html(desc) right?

Comment: Thanks so much for responding Marc. I’m not sure where to use the html() method in the example i posted. I’ve tried but cannot get the html to render as rich text on the output.